# How to split a string by a string in Scala

Tags: string, scala, split

In Ruby, I did:

```
"string1::string2".split("::")
```

In Scala, I can't find how to `split` using a string, not a single character.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your example it does not make a difference, but the `String#split` method in Scala actually takes a `String` that represents a regular expression. So be sure to escape certain characters as needed, like e.g. in `"a..b.c".split("""\.\.""")` or to make that fact more obvious you can call the split method on a `RegEx`: `"""\.\.""".r.split("a..b.c")`.

Comment: Ah yes. I was convinced it took a Regex or a Char, not a String, so it kept complaining.

Comment: I suggest using `\Q` and `\E` instead of doing individual escaping. Just add  `\Q` to the beginning (or `\\Q`, as needed), and a `\E` to the end.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Great idea - any way to escape a string stored in a `var` (constant)?

Comment: @Rubistro You can use `scala.util.matching.Regex.quote`, or Java's equivalent method.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I found that `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(str)` will do that to an arbitrary String literal (surround with \Q and \E).

Answer (score 83):

The REPL is even easier than Stack Overflow. I just pasted your example as is.

> `Welcome to Scala version 2.8.1.final (Java HotSpot Server VM, Java 1.6.0_22).`
>   `Type in expressions to have them evaluated.`
>   `Type :help for more information.`

```
scala> "string1::string2".split("::")
res0: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(string1, string2)
```

Comment: this should be the answer. Moritz strategy of creating a regex works, but this simple solution is better.

Comment: this answer actually answers the question; the currently accepted answer describes a theory that could work, but doesn't describe the actual answer to the asked question.

Comment: There's a problem with split: when you try "::".split("::") you get Nil, but should List("","")

Comment: @Vitamon If that were so, then `"aaaaa".split("a")` => `List("", "", "", "", "", "")` -- which for most purposes doesn't offer any useful information. Would rather interpret as empty.

Answer (score 12):

That line of Ruby should work just like it is in Scala too and return an `Array[String]`.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [Java implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) you see that the parameter to `String#split` will be in fact compiled to a regular expression.

There is no problem with `"string1::string2".split("::")` because ":" is just a character in a regular expression, but for instance `"string1|string2".split("|")` will not yield the expected result. "|" is the special symbol for alternation in a regular expression.

```
scala> "string1|string2".split("|")
res0: Array[String] = Array(s, t, r, i, n, g, 1, |, s, t, r, i, n, g, 2)
```