# Split string by "|~|" in scala

Tags: scala

In python I can do this:

```
In [4]: "string1|~|string2".split("|~|")
Out[4]: ['string1', 'string2']
```

However, the same code in scala does not give me the expected output:

```
scala> "string1|~|string2".split("|~|")
res3: Array[java.lang.String] = Array("", s, t, r, i, n, g, 1, |, ~, |, s, t, r, i, n, g, 2)
```

I looked into this question [How to split a string by a string in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522572/how-to-split-a-string-by-a-string-in-scala)  and it seems that my code should work, but it does not. What am I missing? How do I get my desired output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `split` in Scala is the same as `split` in Java, which expects a regex. So the `|`'s need to be escaped, as they represent an `or` operator within the regex.

```
scala> "string1|~|string2".split("\\|~\\|")
res48: Array[String] = Array(string1, string2)
```

Comment: Or `Regex.quote("|~|")` or '"""\|~\|"""` which looks like an emoticon.