# Scala how to split string and store into array?

Tags: arrays, string, scala

I am currently writing a program that read a string like "2 + 2". It should be split regarding the spaces and store into an Array like Array(2, +, 2). However, I am not sure how to do it within a method (since I usually work in Scala interpreter), access to the result after I split it. I know that in java, you can do String[] arr = string.split("\s+").

```
def eval(s: String): Double = {
var result = 0;
s.split("\\s+");
//how do i retrieve the element that was split?
// I am trying to retrieve, like the above example, the 2 and 2
// perform an addition on them so the method will return a double
result;
}
```

Comment: Which element are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: See [How to split a string by a string in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522572/how-to-split-a-string-by-a-string-in-scala).

Comment: so what's your problem exactly? since `s.split("\\s+");` should work in Scala!? Just assign it to a variable or whatever you wanna do and read the array elements: `val arr = s.split("\\s+");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting is same as in java, you can [read the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34387475/432903).

**Only thing you are missing is accessing the array which is done with `array(index)`**

```
def eval(s: String): Double = {
  val operands = s.split("\\s+")
  operands(0).toDouble + operands(2).toDouble //the last statement is return statement
}

assert(eval("2 + 2") == 4)
```

The above will always do addition even if you do `eval("2 - 2") == 4`

**But if you want to have all operations(`+`, `-`) then do [pattern match](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html) on your `operator` which is index `1`.**

```
def eval(s: String): Double = {
  val operandsWithOperator = s.split("\\s+")

  operandsWithOperator(1) match {
    case "+" => operandsWithOperator(0).toDouble + operandsWithOperator(2).toDouble
    case "-" => operandsWithOperator(0).toDouble - operandsWithOperator(2).toDouble
    case "*" => operandsWithOperator(0).toDouble * operandsWithOperator(2).toDouble
    case "/" => operandsWithOperator(0).toDouble / operandsWithOperator(2).toDouble
  }
}

assert(eval("2 + 2") == 4)
assert(eval("2 - 2") == 0)
assert(eval("2 * 3") == 6)
assert(eval("2 / 2") == 1)
```

And if you want more than two operands, then recurse.

Comment: Don't need the `result` var. Just conclude with the `match` statement.

Comment: tyvm! This is very helpful :>

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern matching to extract the string items and also to match the operator,

```
def eval(s: String): Double = {
  val Array(left, op, right, _*) = s.split("\\s+")
  (left.toDouble, op, right.toDouble) match {
    case (a, "+", b) => a+b
    case _           => Double.NaN  // error value
  }
}
```