# What is this code asking to do?

Tags: scala

```
case class TempData(year:Int,month:Int,Prec:Double,Maxtemp:Int,Meantemp:Int,Mintemp:Int)

def parseLine(line:String):TempData = {
  val p = line.split(",")
  TempData(p(1).toInt,p(4).toInt,p(5).toDouble,p(6).toInt,p(7).toInt,p(8).toInt)  
}
```

Comment: Looks like it parses the comma separated `line` string into a `TempData` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply takes a line(which is CSV) splits it by `,` and creates `TempData` instance from those values.

see example,

```
scala> case class TempData(year:Int,month:Int,Prec:Double,Maxtemp:Int,Meantemp:Int,Mintemp:Int)
defined class TempData

scala> val p = "whatever,2017,whatever,whatever,10,5.0,1000,2000,3000".split(",")
p: Array[String] = Array(whatever, 2017, whatever, whatever, 10, 5.0, 1000, 2000, 3000)

scala> TempData(p(1).toInt,p(4).toInt,p(5).toDouble,p(6).toInt,p(7).toInt,p(8).toInt)
res1: TempData = TempData(2017,10,5.0,1000,2000,3000)
```

which is equivalent to

```
scala> TempData(year=p(1).toInt, month=p(4).toInt, Prec=p(5).toDouble, Maxtemp=p(6).toInt, Meantemp=p(7).toInt, Mintemp=p(8).toInt)
res2: TempData = TempData(2017,10,5.0,1000,2000,3000)
```

read about [String#split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522572/how-to-split-a-string-by-a-string-in-scala) and also [case classes](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/107.html) in scala.